# udev rules not working

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I use ubuntu and I want to have date log when my usb stick is connected. I've created

```
sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/60-my.rules
```

which contains

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ACTION=="add",KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{serial}=="11353000000006E5", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/myusbrule.sh /dev/sdb1"
```

where 11353000000006E5 is serial no. of my pen drive. My shell script myusbrule.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

date >> /home/nilesh/log.log
```

but nothing is updating in log file when I am connecting the pen drive, am I wrong anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

udev does not run run your script on any active terminal, and it does not execute it under the context of a shell: so you cannot expect any standard output to appear on your terminal.
You could try to write on a log file or something like that.

source:   http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run

Comment: I seen the link you attached. I've edited my question, now I am appending date in log file but log file is not updating